# QThread terminate and affinity

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

This example is for testing QThread. The main objective is to be able to run one time consuming blocking method in a dedicated thread and
being able to terminate and restart the thread at any point. The blocking method is a 3rd party lib which is outside our control. I know the documentation of Qt discourages using QThread::terminate but at the moment I do not see any other way.

Below is a pseduo example of the code needed to run in a dedicated thread. There is basically one method which can take 10-15 minutes to process. There is no logical place to add moveToThread to take the affinity back to main thread on QThread::termination, or executiong processEvent to handle a QThread::quit() method.

```
void run()
{
  // initiate variables
  thirdparty lib(var1, var2);
  int res = lib.execute(var3, var4, var6);
  // handle result and exit
}
```

Using Qt 4.7 on Windows 7.

Running the code produces this output

```
Test::doWork thread: QThread(0x219e960) 
Test::started thread: QThread(0x239bce8)
Test::doTerminate thread: QThread(0x239bce8) 
Test::doWork thread: QThread(0x239bce8) 
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x219e960) is not the object's thread (0x239bce8). Cannot move to target thread (0x239bd20)
```

The moveToThread API fails on the second execution of the Test::doWork() method. This appears to be because the Test instance has affinity to another thread (which is terminated at this point). How can I then change the affinity?

What is the recommended way to terminate and restart a QThread? Do I need to delete the Test instance?

The code;

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>
#include "Worker.h"
#include "Windows.h"

class Test : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  QThread* m_thread;
  int      m_state;

public:
    Test() : m_thread(0), m_state(3) { }

public slots:
    void doWork()
    {
      qDebug() << "Test::doWork thread:" << QObject::thread();
      if (!m_thread)
      {
        m_thread = new QThread();
        QObject::moveToThread(m_thread);
        QObject::connect(m_thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(started()));
        QObject::connect(m_thread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(finished()));
        QObject::connect(m_thread, SIGNAL(terminated()), this, SLOT(terminated()));
        m_thread->start();
      }
    }

    void started()
    {      
      qDebug() << "Test::started thread:" << QObject::thread();
      Sleep(60);
    }

    void finished()
    {
      qDebug() << "Test::finished thread:" << QObject::thread();
    }

    void terminated()
    {
      qDebug() << "Test::terminated thread:" << QObject::thread();
    }

    void doTerminate()
    {
      qDebug() << "Test::doTerminate thread:" << QObject::thread();
      QObject::disconnect(m_thread);
      m_thread->terminate();
      m_thread->wait();
      m_thread = NULL;
    }

    int state()
    {
      return m_state;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  Test test;

  test.doWork();
  Sleep(10);

  test.doTerminate();
  Sleep(10);

  test.doWork();
  return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You could push your `Test` object back to main thread before you kill your `m_thread`, but this seems a bit odd thing to do. Why are you killing the thread if you have to start it again?

Comment: You should also think about connecting `m_thread`'s [`finished()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html#finished) signal to it's [`deleteLater()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#deleteLater) slot. Right now you are setting the `m_thread` value to `0`, but i don't see you destroying the object anywhere.

Comment: The third party method is executed with a number of parameters. You might want to terminate an execution if the parameters are incorrect and then restart with different parameters.

Comment: How do I "push you test object back to main thread" ?

Comment: `this->moveToThread(QApplication::instance()->thread());` or something  along those lines.

Comment: I assume this code must be executed in the working thread? The issue with that is the working thread is busy executing a blocking call to a third party library.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using terminate, you can call the more acceptable function quit().

Comment: The QThread::quit docs state "Tells the thread's event loop to exit with return code 0 (success)". Does this interrupt the current event or does it wait for it to finish and then exit?

Comment: I would expect it to finish whatever events it is processing in the event loop and then exit cleanly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue with that approach is that the event being processed is a time consuming task which will tie up system resources and produce data which no long is neeeded. Therefore I opted for a more forcefull approach.

Comment: Why not just connect a signal to a slot in the Test class to stop the task? If the task is in a constant while loop, preventing messages being sent, then call QApplication::processEvents() once in a while.

Comment: I have updated the original post. The issue is that the task is busy with basically one blocking call which can take 10 minute to complete. There is no place to insert QApplication::processEvents(). This design is out of my control.

Comment: Then I think your options are 1) Move the object back to the main thread before calling doWork again. 2) Factor out the 3rd party library into another program and call that with QProcess, 3) Use code injection into the 3rd party library to allow the calling of processEvents.